# Align caption vertically APEXCHARTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, apexcharts

I built this chart using Apex charts

[image: chart]

But both the 'Chart' title and the caption are not aligned, the title should be aligned relative to the graph, and the vertically aligned caption.

the title aligned so by placing the property `align: 'center'`

but my main problem is in the legend, I went behind the documentation and found this command `verticalAlign: 'middle'` to be used inside the ´legend:´ property.

Does anyone know how to make this work properly?

Answer (score 4):

The solution for vertically aligning the legend would be:

```
.apexcharts-legend {
  justify-content: center !important;
  top: 0 !important;
}
```

because you have to force overwrite the default which is `justify-conent: flex-start`

edit:
you also need `top: 0 !important` to really get it centered but that might mess up your other charts

I guess for you this answer is one year too late but maybe it's helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 2):

There is no property called `verticalAlign` for the legend.

You can vertically align the legend to center with CSS

```css
.apexcharts-legend {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This simply does not work with apexcharts-legend. Have you gotten it to work?

Comment: @DavidManess the default seems to be `justify-conent: flex-start;` So you have to add an `!important` -> `justify-content: center !important;`